# Copy sales order grid to custom module

Tags: magento2, module, backend, order-grid

I want to make a copy of the default Sales Order grid in **Magento 2** to my own module. In Magento 1 I have build a custom module to show all backorders. See below:

[image]

Now I want to create this module in Magento 2 too but I can't find how to make a copy of the default Sales Order Grid. For Magento 1 I used this tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

I have already found a lot of tutorials for Magento 2 about creating custom backend modules but none of them describe how te re-use the code for the current/default sales order grid.

Can you simply make a copy of the di.xml to load all the data?

Thanks in advance

Michel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Create admin layout file  and add this code. This will load complete sales order grid. Magento 2 is using ui component just adding the name of component will load the order grid  **sales_order_grid**.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sales_order_grid"/>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```